# What Icon Display Resolutions and Pixel Densities Should I Use?

Tags: xcode, icon, resolution

I am designing an icon for use with an Xcode template and need to know what display-resolution and pixel-density settings I need to use for each of the PNG files I'm exporting from GIMP into my `.iconset` folder.  Specifically, what display resolutions and pixel densities should I use for the `icon_512x512@2x.png`, `icon_512x512.png`, `icon_256x256@2x.png`, `icon_256x256.png`, `icon_128x128@2x.png`, `icon_128x128.png`, `icon_64x64@2x.png`, `icon_64x64.png`, `icon_32x32@2x`, `icon_32x32.png`, `icon_16x16@2x.png`, and `icon_16x16.png` images in my icon set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the resolution given in the name of the image. For @2x images, double the resolution in both directions. PPI does not matter—Apple uses 72 PPI. Do not use any transparency or interlacing.

For example: `icon_512x512@2x.png` is a 1024x1024 image.

Comment: OK, thanks!  I thought that the resolution given in the name that you're supposed to use for each of your icon resources might be significant, but I wasn't sure if the `@2x` part meant double the resolution or double the pixel density.